# Modifications to the gravitational law

Tags: forces, gravity

It was reported in 1986 that the force between two masses may be represented (accounting for the fifth interaction) by 
$$F=\frac{GmM\ (1 + \alpha \mathrm e^d\ (1+ r/\lambda))}{r^2}$$ 
where $\alpha$ approximately -0.007 and $\lambda$ approximately 200 m and $d=-r/\lambda$.

What is the significance $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ here and from where is this derived?

Comment: Reported where?

Comment: Review [screened Coulomb potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) generated by ultra-light particles. The particular "fifth force" canard you are reminiscing on has been both discredited and contradicted by careful rafts of experiments in the intervening 33 years. What on earth brought you back to such dark moments?

Comment: If something is thirty years old and would be revolutionary and impactful if true, it's worth looking a little to see why you haven't heard a lot more about it in the intervening time. Not counting the current bruhaha about X17, "fifth" forces have been announced (or at least trial ballooned) and then abandond three times in my lifetime.